# os.system python function in a while loop

Tags: python, ubuntu, os.system, xdotool

I am trying to make a simple python script to automatically click in ubuntu 14.04.

here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
clickCounter = 0
while clickCounter == 0:
    timeNow = os.system('date +\"%s\"')
    if timeNow > 10:
        os.system('xdotool click 1')
        clickCounter = clickCounter + 1
```

however, for some reason, all it will do is print out the time again and again until i close the terminal. if anyone can help me it would be very appreciated

Comment: [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) returns the *exit status* of the command, not its standard output. And for the love of `$DEITY`, don't shell out to `date` to get the time! There's the entire [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) module!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thank you, i can't believe i forgot about time.time()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you still need to use `os.system` you should do this:

```
timeNow = os.popen('date +\"%s\"').read()
```

A [better way](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/) is using `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(('date +\"%s\"'.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(timeNow, err) = proc.communicate()
```

But as stated in comments - in your case use `time`

Answer (score -1):

os.system returns exit status. If you need to get the command's output to a variable try,

import commands

import os

clickCounter = 0

while clickCounter == 0:

```
timeNow = commands.getoutput('date +\"%s\"')

if timeNow > 10:       

    os.system('xdotool click 1')

    clickCounter = clickCounter + 1
```